# Why can't I use ID multiple times?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

This is not a full code but it fully covers the area of error

```
<body onload="init()">
    <nav>
      <h1 style="font-family:Helvetica;">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li ><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
            <ul>
              <li id="navbar-menu"><a href="#">Sub-menu Item 1</a></li>
              <li id="navbar-menu"><a href="#">Sub-menu Item 2</a></li>
              <li id="navbar-menu"><a href="#">Sub-menu Item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </h1>
    </nav>
<body>
```

There are total of 4 menus.

```
.nav li ul a:hover {
   background: rgb(96, 235, 245);
    color:white;
  }

body {

    color:white;
  }
```

The background colour in nav li ul a:hober appers when I hover over the sub menu. What I intended to do is change that colour wrt time of user. So in my code I deleted my bg color so it won't conflict with java script as I've done the same with body. But it does not work. Here's the complete Java script for my code:

```
function init() {
  function setBackgroundForTimeOfDay() {
    const body = document.querySelector('body');
    const hours = new Date().getHours();

    if (hours < 6 || hours >= 18)
      body.style.background = 'linear-gradient(to right, rgb(39, 38, 38), rgb(245, 96, 96),rgb(39, 38, 38))';

    else
      body.style.background = 'linear-gradient(to right, rgb(39, 38, 38), rgb(96, 235, 245),rgb(39, 38, 38))';
  }
  setBackgroundForTimeOfDay();
  setInterval(setBackgroundForTimeOfDay, 60000);
}

function init1() {
  function setBackgroundForTimeOfDay() {
    const li = document.getElementById('navbar-menu');
    const hours = new Date().getHours();

    if (hours < 6 || hours >= 18)
      li.style.background = 'rgb(245, 96, 96)';

    else
      li.style.background = 'rgb(96, 235, 245)';
  }

  setBackgroundForTimeOfDay();
  setInterval(setBackgroundForTimeOfDay, 60000);
}
init1();
```

Can you please explain what is the problem here

Comment: ID is a **unique** identifier.  If you have multiple elements with the same ID, the ID is no longer unique.  This could cause many errors and unforeseen side-effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't realy clear what you want, but your most important error is that you can't set 3 elements with same `ID`, the `ID` must be unique! Change it with a `class` and change the logic in this way:

```
function init1() {
  function setBackgroundForTimeOfDay() {

    //_______________ getElementById ______________________
    var li = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar-menu'); 

    const hours = new Date().getHours();


    //_______________ and loop through li ___________
    if (hours < 6 || hours >= 18)
        for (var i=0; i < li.length; i++) {
          li[i].style.background = 'rgb(245, 96, 96)';
        }

    else
        for (var i=0; i < li.length; i++) {
          li[i].style.background = 'rgb(96, 235, 245)';
        }
  }

  setBackgroundForTimeOfDay();
  setInterval(setBackgroundForTimeOfDay, 60000);
}
```

Here your edited example: http://jsfiddle.net/gah909cd/

Comment: Hello, Mate. A Very thanks for solving the exact problem I had. When I implemented in my solution, it does not work ;D
I'll figure out what is wrong with my code, thanks. man. Really appreciate the help.

Comment: @JeevaBharathi It was a pleasure :)